# Setting a div to display none when window scroll position is greater

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to hide the div when the window scroll position is greater than the bottom position of the div. I tried to do it myself but I'm doing something wrong. Also got another question since I need a better code to text ratio to submit this question. Why when I alert(); img_top does it say object object?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 var img_height = $("#head").outerHeight();
 var img_top = $("#head").offset();
  var img_bot = img_height + img_top;

  $(window).scroll(function(){
   var wind_pos = $(window).scrollTop();
   $("p").html(wind_pos);
    
    if(wind_pos > img_bot){
   $("#head").addClass("hide");
  }
  });
});
```

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body{
  height: 4000px;
}

#head{
  height: 600px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.hide{
  display: none;
}

p{
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="head">

</div>
<p>
</p>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

[`jQuery.offset()`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) return object representing position of the matched element, you are suppose to read `top` property of it.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var img_height = $("#head").outerHeight();
  var img_top = $("#head").offset().top;
  var img_bot = img_height + img_top;

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var wind_pos = $(window).scrollTop();
    $("p").html(wind_pos);

    if (wind_pos > img_bot) {
      $("#head").addClass("hide");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  height: 4000px;
}

#head {
  height: 600px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}

p {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="head">

</div>
<p>
</p>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Oh yeah now I remember what was missing. Thanks, I will accept this as the answer soon

Answer (score 1):

```
img_top
```

is an object because

```
$("#head").offset();
```

returns an object with top and left offsets,
you have to use

```
$("#head").offset().top
```

in your calculation